# Filter by a column created in a SELECT clause without repeating logic or using CTE

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table with numeric values for a and b, and I want to output a table with the sum of a and b, but only where it's above 5. Like so:

```
SELECT a + b AS c
FROM t
WHERE a + b > 5
```

Is there any elegant way to do this without repeating a + b (in my case, it's a very complicated algorithm that I want to tweak without having to tweak it in two places), and without putting the whole thing in a CTE and then filtering it based on c there? Ideally something as simple as (though I know these don't work) "WHERE c > 5" or "HAVING c > 5".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
select d.c from
(
SELECT a + b AS c
FROM t
) as d
WHERE d.c > 5
```

(note this is not a CTE, it's a subtable, but that may be what you meant anyway)

Of course the other way is to create a view

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lateral`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

```
select c
from 
    t
    crosstab lateral
    (select a + b as c) ctl
where c > 5
```